# scipy's interpn for interpolate high N data

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, scipy, interpolation

I try to interpolate some data using [`scipy.interpolate.interpn`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interpn.html#scipy.interpolate.interpn). It might not be the right function, so please advise me if it's not. I need to interpolate over 3 variables where each have 2 values (8 in total) down to a single point.

Here is a working example for N=2 (I think).

```
from scipy.interpolate import interpn
import numpy as np
points = np.zeros((2, 2))
points[0, 1] = 1
points[1, 1] = 1
values = np.array(([ 5.222, 6.916], [6.499, 4.102]))
xi = np.array((0.108, 0.88))

print(interpn(points, values, xi))  # Gives: 6.462
```

But when I try to use it for a higher dimension, it breaks. I have a feeling it is because how my arrays are constructed.

```
p2 = np.zeros((2, 2, 2))
p2[0,0,1] = 1
p2[0,1,1] = 1
p2[1,0,1] = 1
p2[1,1,1] = 1
v2 = np.array([[[5.222,4.852],
                [6.916,4.377]],
               [[6.499,6.076],
                [4.102,5.729]]])
x2 = np.array((0.108, 0.88, 1))
print(interpn(p2, v2, x2))
```

This gives me the following error message:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/interpolate/interpolate.pyc in interpn(points, values, xi, method, bounds_error, fill_value)
   1680         if not np.asarray(p).ndim == 1:
   1681             raise ValueError("The points in dimension %d must be "
-> 1682                              "1-dimensional" % i)
   1683         if not values.shape[i] == len(p):
   1684             raise ValueError("There are %d points and %d values in "

ValueError: The points in dimension 0 must be 1-dimensional
```

How do I fix my code? Keep in mind I need to interpolate over 3 variables with 2 values in each (`v2.shape = (2, 2, 2)`).

Comment: The first argument `points` is supposed to contain three 1D arrays, defining the x, y, z coordinates of the grid (for interpolation in 3d), or two 1D arrays defining x, y, for interpolation in 2D. You are passing it a 3D array, which is incorrect. What you mean by "interpolate over 3 variables with 2 values" is unclear to me, and probably also to others.

Comment: Maybe your comment just made it work for me. It is also difficult to explain, but let me try to explain what I have done.
I created a new `p2 = np.array(([0,1],[0,1],[0,1]))`. My `x2` values goes between 0 and 1, hence the coordinates in `p2`. This gives me an output without errors, but I'm not sure if it's working.